# Using Parse react query goes to local storage instead of Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, react-native, parse-react

I have an observe function in a react native app that is needed by the Parse react mixin:

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var ParseReact = require('parse-react');
var React = require('react-native');
var PollingPage = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],
  observe: function (props, state) {
    var inOutQuery = (new Parse.Query('IsOut'));
    return state.isLoading ? {inOuts: inOutQuery} : null;
  }, 
//etc


package.json:
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parse": "^1.6.7",
    "parse-react": "^0.5.0"
  }
```

however when this is run it goes off to look in local storage:

```
  getItem: function getItem(path) {
    return localStorage.getItem(path);
  },
```

Not to sure what is going on here.

I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/106369/integrating-parse-react-native-ios#comments

The error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because `window.localStorage` not exist in [`JavaScriptCore`](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore). `localStorage` is a part of [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), but `JavaScriptCore` is just an javascript engine, not "web browser". You should use [AsyncStorage](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#content) instead of `localStorage`.

Please see this [official doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#content) for more information about RN js runtime.

[EDIT]

I think you used the wrong lib. From [ParseReact](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact#getting-started):

> As of version 1.6, the Parse JS SDK has a different build for React Native. If you're using Parse+React on React Native, you'll need to require the 'parse-react/react-native' package instead.

and you can also check `\node_modules\parse\lib\react-native\`, there are 3 difference storage implement: `StorageController.browser.js`, `StorageController.default.js` and `StorageController.react-native.js`. In `StorageController.react-native.js`, the `getItem` function look like that:

```
getItemAsync: function getItemAsync(path) {
  var p = new _ParsePromise2['default']();
  _reactNative.AsyncStorage.getItem(path, function (err, value) {
    if (err) {
      p.reject(err);
    } else {
      p.resolve(value);
    }
  });
  return p;
},
```

Comment: Thanks, so this is an issue with the Parse React library?

Comment: @Nikos No, seams you used wrong lib. I edited more info for that.